# OnClick left and right arrow icon it should select the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This is the week date calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ26G.png)

I have a week calendar. The problem is when i click on right arrow icon it selects the next radio button automatically, but when i click on left arrow it doesn't work and if I comment the right-arrow code the left arrow works. Can anyone give me the fiddle example for it. I giving the code which I wrote:

jQuery:

```
$('.left_arrow').on('click', function(e) {
  var value = $('.time-slot input[type=radio]:checked').attr('data-attr');
  console.log(e.target, value);
  if (parseInt(value) > 0) {
    $($('.time-slot input[type=radio]')[(parseInt(value) - 1)]).attr("checked", true)
  }
});

$('.right_arrow').on('click', function(e) {
  var value = $('.time-slot input[type=radio]:checked').attr('data-attr');
  if (parseInt(value) < 6) {
    $($('.time-slot input[type=radio]')[(parseInt(value) +
      1)]).attr("checked", true)
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a working demo? like in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: use `.prop("checked", true)` instead of `attr("checked", true)`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :)